# Displaying INNER JOIN results as HTML table on webpage?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT first, COUNT(FIRST) FROM techs INNER JOIN ros ON techs.id =  ros.writtenby GROUP BY ID";
```

That gives the desired output of:

| first | COUNT(FIRST) |
| --- | --- |
| Eric | 88 |
| John | 11 |

I have no earthly idea how to display this EXACT table onto a PHP/HTML page. I've created tables based off of queries but it's basically just displaying database table data. I have a feeling the INNER JOIN is the root of my issue since it's not an actual table in the database, rather just results from my query. If this isn't apparent enough already I'm very much a beginner at coding in general so be kind. Lol.

Comment: Please try to explain your problem using another words

Comment: 1. You don't know how to make html template to display queried data to display data?

Comment: 2. Your query returns wrong data?

Comment: 3. You don't know how to execute SQL query using php?

Comment: 1. YES! I cant make the HTML template to display the queried data, the query results are correct

Comment: There's nothing about JOIN that makes generating the HTML table from the results any different from some other query.

Comment: If you know how to do it with non-joined queries, why do you think it's different with join?

Comment: I don't understand how to call and then display the "count(first)" column of my query results, since "count(first)" isn't an actual column in either of the tables I am generating the result from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

> I don't understand how to call and then display the "`count(first)`" column of my query results, since "`count(first)" isn't an actual column in either of the tables I am generating the result from.

If only that's your problem, use alias, like:

```
SELECT first, COUNT(FIRST) AS my_count FROM techs INNER JOIN ros ON techs.id =  ros.writtenby GROUP BY ID
```

> **Note** that above is the query you posted, just with " `AS my_count`" added.

Comment: You are awesome. THANK YOU!

Comment: @orangutan Consider to mark as accepted and/or upvoting (there should be a checkmark somewhere above).